# Added first column in Select Case SQL, can't get the second to stay

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

Trying to learn SQL on my own, and I updated this table correctly with this first statement, and the column OFF_DIVISION stayed in the Temp_NFL2015 table.

```
SELECT *, case when OffenseTeam in ('BUF', 'MIA', 'NYJ','NE') then 'AFC EAST' 
when OffenseTeam in ('BAL','CIN','CLE','PIT') THEN 'AFC NORTH'
when OffenseTeam in ('HOU','IND','JAC','TEN') THEN 'AFC SOUTH'
when OffenseTeam in ('DEN','KC','OAK','SD') THEN 'AFC WEST'
when OffenseTeam in ('DAL','NYG','PHI','WAS') THEN 'NFC EAST'
when OffenseTeam in ('CHI','DET','MIN','GB') THEN 'NFC NORTH'
when OffenseTeam in ('ATL','CAR','NO','TB') THEN 'NFC SOUTH'
when OffenseTeam in ('ARI','STL','SEA','SF') THEN 'NFC WEST' END AS OFF_DIVISION
INTO nfl.dbo.Temp_NFL2015
from NFL2015$
```

Now I have a working column in Temp_NFL2015 called OFF_Division. The table keeps the column in it when I Select * from the table.

But I am now having a problem creating the DEF_Division Column. If I run the below code, I get the results I want, but the column doesn't stay in the table permanently. I tried using INTO, but that didn't work. How can I save the below results into the table permanently? THANK YOU

```
SELECT *, case when DefenseTeam in ('BUF', 'MIA', 'NYJ','NE') then 'AFC EAST' 
when DefenseTeam in ('BAL','CIN','CLE','PIT') THEN 'AFC NORTH'
when DefenseTeam in ('HOU','IND','JAC','TEN') THEN 'AFC SOUTH'
when DefenseTeam in ('DEN','KC','OAK','SD') THEN 'AFC WEST'
when DefenseTeam in ('DAL','NYG','PHI','WAS') THEN 'NFC EAST'
when DefenseTeam in ('CHI','DET','MIN','GB') THEN 'NFC NORTH'
when DefenseTeam in ('ATL','CAR','NO','TB') THEN 'NFC SOUTH'
when DefenseTeam in ('ARI','STL','SEA','SF') THEN 'NFC WEST' END AS DEF_DIVISION

from nfl.dbo.Temp_NFL2015
```

Comment: which RDMS you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You should first add the column to the actual table, you are not really creating it, you are just selecting it which will be available only during your query(unless you save it some where)

So, for ANSI-Sql since you didn't provide any DBMS :

```
ALTER TABLE nfl.dbo.Temp_NFL2015
ADD DEF_Division VARCHAR(30)
```

And then update it according to your logic:

```
UPDATE nfl.dbo.Temp_NFL2015
SET DEF_Devision = case when DefenseTeam in ('BUF', 'MIA', 'NYJ','NE') then 'AFC EAST' 
                        when DefenseTeam in ('BAL','CIN','CLE','PIT') THEN 'AFC NORTH'
                        when DefenseTeam in ('HOU','IND','JAC','TEN') THEN 'AFC SOUTH'
                        when DefenseTeam in ('DEN','KC','OAK','SD') THEN 'AFC WEST'
                        when DefenseTeam in ('DAL','NYG','PHI','WAS') THEN 'NFC EAST'
                        when DefenseTeam in ('CHI','DET','MIN','GB') THEN 'NFC NORTH'
                        when DefenseTeam in ('ATL','CAR','NO','TB') THEN 'NFC SOUTH'
                        when DefenseTeam in ('ARI','STL','SEA','SF') THEN 'NFC WEST' END
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for helping me understand this better. I figured the Alter Table had something to do with it, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both case statements in the first sql statement for better performance than the alter table / update approach.  My personal preference is usually to have a table of TeamAbbr and ConfAbbr that I would join to twice, once for offense and once for defence.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am going to do JOIN this evening, haven't gotten that far!